# Spree: Replace a class attribute using Deface

Tags: spree

I would like to replace class from "columns four" to "columns three" using Deface.

```
<aside id="sidebar" class="columns four" data-hook>
  <%= yield :sidebar %>
</aside>
```

I'm not sure what I need to put for action and source. This is what I have so far.

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "shared/_sidebar", 
                     :name => "grid", 
                     :set_attributes => '.columns three', 
                     :attributes => {:class => 'pretty', :title => 'This is a link'})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path       => 'spree/shared/_sidebar',
  :name               => 'grid',
  :set_attributes     => '.columns.four',
  :attributes         => {:class => 'columns three', :title => 'This is a link'})
```

you don't need `:source` or `:action` with `:set_attributes`. Notice that `set_attributes` is for selecting what exists currently (i.e what you want to change) and you provide new attributes with `:attributes` option.

Edit: deface for your comment's question:

```
Deface::Override.new(
  :virtual_path       => 'path/to/view',
  :name               => 'some name',
  :replace => %{[erb-loud]:contains(' !content_for?(:sidebar) ? "sixteen" : "twelve" ')},
  text: '<%= !content_for?(:sidebar) ? "thirteen" : "twelve" %>"'
)
```

In newer versions of Deface you should be able to use also `erb[loud]`, just small syntax change.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind helping me with one more thing? How can I change the "twelve" to "thirteen"? I want the ternary operator to be "sixteen": "thirteen". Here's the code=> <div id="content" class="columns <%= !content_for?(:sidebar) ? "sixteen" : "twelve" %>" data-hook>

Comment: @wag0325: sure, I just haven't noticed you wrote comment, edited my answer.